# How to improve zip file's compression using 7za command line 7zip

Tags: command-line, compression, zip, 7-zip, archiving

When I pack my project with 7zip, it has 7MB. When I pack it with [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) the file has 17MB.

Now I need JSZip to perform some subtle changes which 7zip does not allow (at least not for zip anyway). However, after the file is archived, I'd rather have 7zip open it and pack it better. How to do that?

What I'm after is zip to zip archive conversion, just with better compression.

Comment: Can you not just extract the file(s) from the archive in the JSZipped format with 7Z? Have you tried? What is the file extension of the files compressed with JSZip?

Comment: What does JSZip do that you can't live without?

Comment: I do not want to make temporary files on disk just to pack them again. What I need is to add generated strings into the archive. `7z` supports accepting files from stdin, [but not for zip files](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/stdin.htm).

Comment: Did you try setting the compression level to 9 in the options?